# Автозапуск скрипта при запуске термукса

Tags: python, консоль, termux

У меня есть скрипт на питоне, который при запуске должен записать другой скрипт в автозагрузку термукса. Можно ли как то с помощью модуля os выполнить команду для прописывания в автозапуск скрипта? Нужно что бы при запуске термукса фоново запускался питон скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

```
python path/to/my/script.py
```

Добавить в `~/.bashrc` file